# How do we show that a formula is valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In Enderton logic book they call P a logically valid formula if for every interpretation M and value function $\lambda$ $P^{(M,\lambda)}$ is true.

I have trouble using this to prove a formula is valid or not.
It seems that I need induction as it says "every interpretation"

So I just used some formula in the book to practice the definition

$$(\lnot P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow ((\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q) \rightarrow P)$$

Can someone explain the validity for this formula?

Comment: For propositional calculus the tool is [Truth Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Comment: For predicate logic, every "instance" of a tautology is *valid*.

Comment: In most cases, a "semantic" argument will be most effective than using TT. For the formula above, reason by contradiction, assuming that the antecedent is True while the consequent is False.

Comment: The validity of that statement does not depend upon any interpretation of the propositions. You only need to consider whether or not $P$ and $Q$ are true.

Comment: @JohnDouma In propositional logic an "interpretation" is precisely a truth assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a model where $(\lnot P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow ((\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q) \rightarrow P)$ is false.

Then as the only way to falsify a statement of the form $\phi \to \psi$ is to have $\phi$ true and $\psi$ false:

In this model we must have $(\lnot P \rightarrow Q)$ true and $((\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q) \rightarrow P)$ false, and the latter implies that
$(\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q)$ true and $P$ false. Then $\lnot P$ is true in that model and so $\lnot Q$ is true as well (by $(\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q)$ ), so $Q$ is false. But then $(\lnot P \rightarrow Q)$ is "true $\to$ false" which is **false** , a contradiction. So no model exists where it is false, so it's valid.